# Why I get the foolowing "Settings isn't responding. ... close it", when i turn Wifi on? (even in Safe Mode!) /Android 501 & Sams S4

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, system-freeze

Android 5.0.1 /Samsung S4, Not rooted.

Why I get the following message dialog "Settings isn't responding. Do you want to close it?", every time when i turn Wifi on? (even when phone is started in Safe Mode! ...ie without any external app).

In fact EVERYTIME I navigate to Settings and push the wifi to ON itself, it gets stuck there for a minute and the following dialog pops up, with 2 choices: "Wait" and "Close". If closed is pressed then Settings closes and wifi never gets ON. If Wait is pressed then it hangs for another minute and same dialog pops up. Again, if Wait is pressed and after another minute ONLY THEN settings proceeds and turns finally the wifi ON. And proceeds working normally. SOMETIMES: an extra step of dialog appears making the total of appearances at the most 4 times. But even then it finally turns ON and settings is anew functional.

Needless to say while Settings is trying to turn wifi ON, no other function in Settings can be selected and processed...The whole process of Settings is frozen.

I searched internet already and haven't found (tried MANY of proposed) a solution, even though a lot of people experience similar problems with turning wifi on and getting stuck - regardless of type of phone and android version.

It also gets stuck even if i try to ON the wifi directly from the top task bar by pressing the (green) button - it gets stuck in faded green color without turning wifi ON.

Please, has this problem been solved reliably by anyone? All info is much appreciated.

Comment: Tried backing up and flashing a factory firmware? Sounds like a near-dead WiFi module to me, probably want to verify that.

Comment: Try to make factory reset.

Comment: Thank you both "Andy Yan" and "Suncatcher" for the suggestion. No, I haven't flash a new firmware/factory reset. I would very much try to avoid the hassle of it. In fact IF I go through that, I consider rooting also and maybe flashing a custom firmware too. Actually the Wifi does work - even after this 3-4 minute delay, so for the moment I go by with that. Please could you elaborate on how to verify the "near-dead wifi module" ...or maybe you mean if problem persists after flashing fact firmware that would lead to prove the module(hardware problem) is responsible?